# How to find out when the device is held upright horizontally and vertically using UIAccelerometer

Tags: iphone

How to find when the ipod is held straight up in the air - both horizontally and vertically.

Can any one help me ?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: you should do some research before asking. i suppose this question has been answered before

Comment: sorry tomen. I searched but didnt got any answer . Can you tell me the answer plz?

Comment: By "straight up in the air" do you mean the orientation of the iPod such that it is perpendicular to the ground, or the movement of the iPod from chest-level to above your head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would read the accelerometer values. A value of approx 1 on one axis, and approx 0 on all others would indicate that the devices was stationary and in a vertical (or horizontal) orientation : the 1 indicates 1 G acting through the plane of the device. Of course this would only work on Earth :-) I guess checking for 0 on all but one axis would eliminate that bug!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, maybe with the UIDevice orientation you can know it easily.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(orientationObserver) name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object: nil];
```

On the selector take the orientation with

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

This way you avoid check the acceleration and know the orientation of the device.

```
 UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
 UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
 UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
 UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
 UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,
 UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
```